# How to use result of SQL union in MariaDB? (add calculation column, join with another table, etc.)

Tags: sql, mariadb

i have problem with querying in mariaDB 10.4, in union syntax.

i run this query, it is OK, no error :

```
-- select * from
((select HireDate HireTermDate from employee)
union
(select TerminationDate HireTermDate from employee
where TerminationDate is not null)
order by HireTermDate asc)
```

but, if i remove the comment on "select * from...", like this :

```
select * from
((select HireDate HireTermDate from employee)
union
(select TerminationDate HireTermDate from employee
where TerminationDate is not null)
order by HireTermDate asc)
```

it got error, why is that?

many thanks in advance

Comment: I think your order by needs to be outside the )'s `select * from ((select HireDate HireTermDate from employee) union (select TerminationDate HireTermDate from employee where TerminationDate is not null))  as q order by q.HireTermDate asc`

Comment: hmm, it works! many many thanks, sorry for my lack of experience

Answer (score 0):

When you removed the comments then the query with union became a derived table.

And that requires an alias name.

> ```
> create table test (id int)
> insert into test values (1), (2)
> ```

> ```
> select * from
> (
>  select id as num from test where id=1
>  union
>  select id from test where id=2
>  order by num
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
> ```

> ```
> select * from
> (
>  select id as num from test where id=1
>  union
>  select id from test where id=2
> ) AS q
> order by num
> ```
>
> ```
> | num |
> | --: |
> |   1 |
> |   2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=8e407210d23841e89729bbab3a5ee4c7)*